# How to record using jmeter Http proxy server with "Automatic proxy configuration URL" (i.e .pac file )in proxy in browser

Tags: proxy, jmeter

In Jmeter, I am not able to record any external website from our company proxy server.
I have to use option "Automatic proxy configuration URL" (i.e one .pac file )in to browser if I dont know how to configure it in Jmeter to do successful recording.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PAC fiels contain javascript which is executed by the browser to decide which proxy URL they want to use. JMeter is not a browser so it does not run this code. The solution is simply to resolve which proxy this script returns and input this value into JMeter directly, you can do this using the dev tools on most browsers, or just ask the IT dept. that maintains the thing to tell you the direct address.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. Is is solved by getting IP address and port from IT department as you said. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Same question with solution](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Newbie-Not-able-to-record-the-script-under-corporate-proxy-td5139668.html) in Jmeter mailing archive.
2. [Jmeter: Using a Proxy Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server).

Comment: I updated the other answer. Since it gave the solution and not just the link. And it did solve the problem. Please provide a short info about the solution.